# Does C++14 require that the delete expression must call `void operator ::delete(void*, std::size_t)` instead of `void ::operator delete(void*)`?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, c++14

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

```
void operator delete  (void*);                                    (1)   
void operator delete[](void*);                                    (2)   
void operator delete  (void*, const std::nothrow_t&);             (3)   
void operator delete[](void*, const std::nothrow_t&);             (4)   
void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)                          (5)
void operator delete[](void*, std::size_t)                        (6)
void operator delete(void*, std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)   (7)
void operator delete[](void*, std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) (8)
```

> (5-8) Called instead of (1-4) if a user-defined replacement is
>   provided. The standard library implementations are identical to (1-4).

I believe the cited statement is correct; however, I cannot confirm it as per the draft C++14 standard n3797 .

I examined 3.7.4 and 18.6, and found nothing to explicitly require the delete expression must call `void ::operator delete(void*, std::size_t)` instead of `void ::operator delete(void*)` if the former exists.

Could you refer me to the right page of the draft standard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The selection of deallocation functions is explained in:

**5.3.5 Delete [expr.delete]**

> 10 If the type is complete and if deallocation function lookup ﬁnds
>   both a usual deallocation function with only a pointer parameter and a
>   usual deallocation function with both a pointer parameter and a size
>   parameter, then the selected deallocation function shall be the one
>   with two parameters. Otherwise, the selected deallocation function
>   shall be the function with one parameter.